# Выделение новой сущности

Tags: база-данных, spring, проектирование, spring-boot

Создаю приложение деля функционал на слои Model, Service, DAO.

Есть три сущности `"Товар"`, `"Клиент"` и `"Заказ"`. Соответственно каждая сущность имеет Model, Service и DAO слои.

Т.к. отношение между сущностями `"Товар"` и `"Заказ"` соответствует `Многое ко многим`. Т.е. в одном `"Заказe"` может быть один и более `"Товаров"`, а один `"Товар"` может находится в одном и более `"Заказов"`. Важный момент: две сущности при соединении должны хранить еще один атрибут "ДатаВремяСоединения", другими словами, когда именно был добавлен товар к Заказу.

**Возникает вопрос**

Как в рамках архитектуры Model, Service, DAO организовать отношение `Многое ко многим`?
Стоит ли выделять еще одну сущность (ведь придется создавать дополнительную таблицу в БД, а значит описывать слой Model)?
Либо отношения `Один ко многим` и `Многое ко многим` решаются в рамках сущностей имеющих это отношение?

Comment: аннотация `@ManyToMany`

Comment: @Etki а в случае если две сущности при соединении должны хранить дополнительный атрибут, скажем время их соединения (ДатаВремя когда `"Товар"` добавлен в `"Заказ"`)? Как быть в таком случае?

Comment: то это не многие ко многим

Comment: @Etki спасибо! Понял что `@many-to-many` использует 3-юю таблицу с идентификаторами двух сущностей `"Заказ"` и `"Товар"`. Тогда, если необходимо помимо связывания двух сущностей, хранить еще атрибут, скажем время добавления идентификаторов этих двух сущностей в 3-юю таблицу, то мне скорее всего нужно выделять новую сущность? По типу `"Обращение"`, где будет фигурировать нужный мне атрибут "ДатаВремя"?

Comment: Да, возможно, и есть способ запихнуть это в many-to-many, но де-факто это уже отдельная сущность, имеющая many-to-one к двум другим. С точки зрения производительности и запросов - они должны быть практически идентичными.